# Excel - how do I combine values from one worksheet to another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel worksheets. They each have 3 columns: Job Title, Name, Task Completion.

I started working on worksheet one annotating task completion when worksheet two got pushed out with updated names of people who joined our company. Now I have an outdated worksheet and need to "push" the data associated with each name in worksheet one to worksheet two. Worksheet two already contains the same names as worksheet one, but with a bunch of added names. What is the best way to do this without going name by name and updating their task completion box?

Tried to do it one by one, but it is incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a temporary 4th column with an XLOOKUP formula. Something roughly like this:

```
=if(XLOOKUP(this_rows_employee_name, other_sheets_employee_column, other_sheets_employee_column, -1) > 0, "This employee is in the other file", "This employee is NOT in the other file")
```

Then you can filter the table for only employees NOT in the other file, and simply copy paste. Let me know if this works for you (you will need to write your own cells in the formula).